# Obtain value from Gridview using JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

So I have learned how to pop up an alert by focusing a gridview cell, but I'm not sure how to make it display the value of the cell.
Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewSLds" runat="server" CellPadding="0" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Both" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCreated="gridviewSLds_RowCreated">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="Metric" SortExpression="item" ReadOnly="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox onfocusin="select()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("item") %>'
                    ID="txtfocus" class="alertpopup" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Control Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox onfocusin="select()" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("itemCtrlType") %>'
                    ID="txtfocus2" class="modalpopup2" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alertpopup').focus(function () {
        var itemvalue = $('.alertpopup').val();
        alert(itemvalue);
    });
});
```

The problem is that this gives me the value of the first cell in the column. Not the one I focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `$('.alertpopup').val();` Though `$('.alertpopup')` selects all of the elements matching your selector, it ends up just using the first one selected. However, the `this` context of your callback function is set to the HTML element that was focused. So you can do this instead and it will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.alertpopup').focus(function () {
        var itemvalue = $(this).val(); // By selecting `this` you select the focused element
        alert(itemvalue);
    });
});
```